# Leur absence de / du désir de communiquer avec moi est évidente

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

> Plus les minutes s’écoulent, plus leur absence **de** désir de communiquer
> avec moi est évidente.

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi il faut écrire *leur absence **de** désir de communiquer
avec moi* et non *leur absence **du** désir de communiquer avec moi*. À mon avis, *de communiquer avec moi* devrait définir le mot "désir", c'est pourquoi il faudrait employer l'article défini "absence **du**...".

Comment: Larousse: EXPRESSIONS
**En l'absence de quelque chose**, de quelqu'un, faute de cela, de cette personne. Un peu de recherche dans les dicos peut vous aider....C'est une expression idiomatique.

Comment: @Lambie C'est plus compliqué que ça. Dire que c'est une expression idiomatique n'explique pas pourquoi l'article défini est présent si je dis *en l'absence du directeur/des représentants de la direction/ aucune décision n'a été prise*.

Comment: @None Et oui bien sûr. Voilà l'amorce d'une réponse. L'utilisation de la préposition *de* et l'article partitif. J'ai posté cela pour montrer qu'il est bon de donner un minimum de recherches, n'est-ce pas?

Answer (score 2):

***L'absence de désir*** signifie que le désir est absent, qu'ils n'ont pas envie de communiquer avec moi. C'est l'idée que tu souhaites exprimer.

En revanche, la phrase ***leur absence du désir** de communiquer* s'oppose à *leur présence dans le désir de communiquer* comme ***leur absence du théâtre*** s'oppose *leur présence dans le théâtre/au théâtre*. Autant *leur absence du théâtre* est compréhensible, autant *leur absence du désir* est improbable.

Ici, *absence* et *présence* signifient respectivement *ne pas faire partie/ne pas être là* et *faire partie/être là*. Ce qui est absent ou présent, c'est ce dont on parle, ici *leur* (*eux*). Si *leur* fait référence à des personnes, ça signifie que ces personnes ne font pas partie du désir de communiquer avec moi, ce qui n'a pas vraiment de sens. D'ailleurs, Google ne trouve qu'une seule occurrence de la séquence *leur absence du désir*, la question à laquelle je réponds...

Une autre façon de présenter la différence entre les deux proposition est de dire qu'avec *l'absence **de** désir de communiquer*, c'est **ce désir** particulier de communiquer qui est absent, mais avec *leur absence **du** désir de communiquer*, ce sont **eux** qui sont absents du désir, si tant est que ça signifie quelque chose.

Comment: _Ce qui est absent ou présent, c'est ce dont on parle, ici leur. Si leur fait référence à des personnes, ça signifie que ces personnes ne font pas partie du désir de communiquer avec moi, ce qui n'a pas vraiment de sens._ --- Désolée, je ne comprends plus rien. Pourquoi "leur" n'est pas compatible avec "du désir" ? // _Google ne trouve aucune occurrence de la séquence leur absence du désir_  --- OK, j'essayerai de me souvenir que c'est ainsi...

Comment: Avec *leur absence de désir de*, c'est le *leur "non-désir" de*, le contraire de *leur désir de* alors que *leur absence du désir de communiquer*, c'est le contraire de *leur présence dans le désir de communiquer* mais ça n'a pas de sens car des personnes ne sont pas quelque chose qu'on met dans un désir de communiquer. Le désir de communiquer est quelque chose que l'on a ou que l'on a pas, qui se mesure. On ne peut pas y trouver des personnes.

Comment: Peut-être en anglais. Leur absence de désir de communiquer: *Their lack of desire to communicate*, Leur absence du désir : *The fact the guys are not part of the desire to communicate* (ce qui n'a pas de sens).

Comment: Je pense que je comprends mieux ce que tu voulais dire, merci. Mais ce désir, qu'il soit présent ou non, est défini par "communiquer avec moi", "communiquer avec moi" le décrit, donc le mot "désir" devrait aussi être défini, malgré le fait que ce désir est absent, qu'il n'existe pas. Je me concentre à présent sur le "désir de communiquer avec moi", j'ajoute "absence" par la suite. Pourquoi ma logique ne fonctionne pas ici ? :(

Comment: Tu peux éventuellement dire ***l**'absence du désir de communiquer avec moi*, c'est à dire ce désir particulier de communiquer est absent, mais ***mon** absence du désir* impose que c'est toi qui est absente, pas le désir.

Comment: _mon absence du désir impose que c'est toi qui est absente, pas le désir_ --- Ah, je pense que je commence à comprendre. Je relirai tout cela demain aussi. Mais pourquoi ce sujet est si compliqué... "l'absence du désir" est possible, mais "mon absence du désir" non... Donc la phrase _Plus les minutes s’écoulent, plus l'absence de **leur** désir de communiquer avec moi est évidente_ serait possible ? En russe, il est possible de dire "mon absence de désir" = "absence de mon désir", la vie est belle :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132000/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-oreste).

Answer (score -3):

Voici une excellente explication de la différence entre l'utilisation de la préposition de et les partitifs:

> L’article partitif se place devant des noms de choses non dénombrables
> ou pour indiquer qu’il s’agit d’une partie seulement de ce que
> constitue le nom : je mange du pain.
>
> **L’article partitif (du, de la, des) associe la préposition de à un
> article défini (le, la, l’, les)**. PAR EXEMPLE: *absence **du** désir*

> **L’article peut manquer devant des compléments ayant une valeur
> déterminative : une statue de bronze.** PAR EXEMPLE: *absence **de** désir*
>
> **La préposition de introduit aussi un complément du nom. Le rapport
> entre ce complément introduit par la préposition de et le nom est
> variable :** appartenance (le chien de Paul), provenance (le train de
> Paris), l’utilisation, la matière… PAR EXEMPLE: *l'absence **de** désir*
>
> Enfin, **la préposition peut n’avoir aucun sens, n’exprimer aucun
> rapport : c’est une préposition dite vide : rien de nouveau.** NE S'APPLIQUE PAS ICI
>
> La maison de retraite,  la maison d’hôte, palais de justice, palais de
> la découverte : il s’agit de la préposition utilisée pour exprimer
> l’utilisation, le rôle de cette maison, de ce palais. La grève de la
> faim : préposition vide.

[préposition et partitifs](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/preposition-de-article-partitif/)

J'ai signalé en gras les cas qui semblent probables. D'autres pourraient avoir d'autres lectures. Toutefois, la deuxième explication est de mise ici pour le partitif. [absence **du** désir]. Il faut aussi mentionner que Larousse dit: "en absence de" est une expression. Dans ce sens-là, c'est invariable et s'accorderait avec les explications 2,3 e 4 en gras.

Comment: Cette réponse a reçu **quatre votes négatifs**.  Incroyable !

Comment: À ce jour, deux seulement.

Comment: Mais non, cela a changé. C'était quatre avant. Alors, à ce jour, bof.

Comment: Un downvote = deux points de réputation en moins, hier tu avais deux downvotes, aujourd'hui tu en as un troisième.

Comment: Je m'en fiche, franchement. On peut très bien répondre à la question en suivant les explications donné par le monsieur qui a écrit le texte ci-dessus. C'est facile à suivre et très clair.

Comment: Si on peut répondre facilement à la question à partir de cette citation, pourquoi ne pas le faire ? Je ne vois que des hypothèses incertaines.

Comment: C'est quoi "absence du désir" et "absence de désir" entre parenthèses??

Comment: Je n'en sais rien. Ce n'est pas clair. Est-ce que tu veux dire que dans *absence du désir*, le *du* est un article partitif, ou alors les deux étoiles signifient que c'est faux ? D'autre part, est-ce que ta réponse dit que le rôle de *de* dans *absence de désir* est le même que celui de *de* dans *statue de bronze* ?  Ce serait une absence faite de désir ?

Answer (score -3):

Je crois que la collection suivante de cas d'usage de « du » ([page réf.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22absence%20du%20d%C3%A9sir%20de%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)), dans des ouvrages récents et tous d'auteurs d'un niveau de culture élevé, ne laisse aucun doute : il existe un choix entre  « de » (préposition « de » avec effacement de « du » massif — *de du* pain → *de pain* (J'ai besoin *de du* pain → J'ai besoin *de* pain.)) et « du », c'est à dire la contraction de « de le », où « le » est l'article défini en fonction de détermination.

[l'absence du désir de savoir, l'absence du désir de vérité](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Du_texte_%C3%A0_la_parole/t82wj8zkX9gC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22absence+du+d%C3%A9sir+de%22&pg=PA85&printsec=frontcover)

[L'absence du désir de sa mère](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_Violence_f%C3%A9minine/WkrJCgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22absence+du+d%C3%A9sir+de%22&pg=PT63&printsec=frontcover)

[l'absence du désir de l'Autre maternel](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_paradoxes_de_l_autisme/JfCVDAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22absence+du+d%C3%A9sir+de%22&pg=PT38&printsec=frontcover)

[l'absence du désir de recevoir des matériaux nutritifs](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/De_l_inflammation/pLhEAAAAcAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22absence+du+d%C3%A9sir+de%22&pg=PA42&printsec=frontcover)

[L'absence du désir de nuire](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_alchimie_du_yoga_selon_Goraksa/-9uVDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22absence+du+d%C3%A9sir+de%22&pg=PT167&printsec=frontcover)

[Absence du désir de désirer](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Approche_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9tique_et_psychanalytique/d9tXDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22absence+du+d%C3%A9sir+de%22&pg=PT188&printsec=frontcover)

[absence du désir de boire](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_Diagnostic_en_m%C3%A9decine_chinoise/j7nrDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22absence+du+d%C3%A9sir+de%22&pg=PA803&printsec=frontcover)

[l'absence du désir de voir](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_partie_et_le_tout/CzjKcFOBNWkC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22absence+du+d%C3%A9sir+de%22&pg=PA198&printsec=frontcover)

[de l'absence d'amour maternel, de l'absence du désir de Pip](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_Grandes_Esp%C3%A9rances_de_Charles_Dicke/0KObDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22absence+du+d%C3%A9sir+de%22&pg=PT204&printsec=frontcover)

*La référence ci-dessus est intéressante en cela que l'on trouve à la suite l'une de l'autre l'utilisation de « de » et de « du ».*

[**en** l'absence du désir de l'Autre](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Du_divin_au_divan/EZkoDAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22absence+du+d%C3%A9sir+de%22&pg=PT202&printsec=frontcover)

[l'absence du désir de Dieu](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_femmes_de_douleur/Sw-erL3-Cz0C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22absence+du+d%C3%A9sir+de%22&pg=PA34&printsec=frontcover)

[l'absence du désir de puissance](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_grand_livre_du_bouddhisme/f0VjT2aNGqgC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22absence+du+d%C3%A9sir+de%22&pg=PA217&printsec=frontcover)

[Absence du désir de réconfort et d'attention](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Attachement_et_th%C3%A9orie_de_l_esprit/NOCbBAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22absence+du+d%C3%A9sir+de%22&pg=PT191&printsec=frontcover)

Pour savoir quel choix convient dans la phrase du questionneur, on s'interroge d'abord sur ce qui justifie l'article défini « le » en fonction de déterminatif dans les occurences qui ont été rassemblées ci-dessus. On voit, mais  peut-être pas si facilement, qu'il est justifié parce que l'auteur avance le cas de désir particulier auquel il réfère comme étant connu.

> (LBU) L'article défini s'emploie devant le nom pour indiquer qu'il
> s'agit d'un être ou d'une chose connus du locuteur et de l'interlocuteur (c'est l'article notoire de Damourette et Pichon).

Dans la phrase, on voit que « communiquer » est modifié par « avec moi » ; aussi, il ne s'agit pas du désir de communiquer tout simple que l'on est prêt à accepter selon un point de vue psychologique en tant que concept reconnu, si l'on n'a pas déjà fait cela. « Communiquer avec moi » ne peut être, à priori qu'un désir connu de personne, qui est trop particulier pour que l'on puisse l'avancer comme connu. Tout dépend donc du contexte. Telle que la phrase est présentée le choix indiqué est « de », c'est à dire il n'a pas été question de ce désir dans ce qui précède. Cependant il est aisé de construire un contexte qui justifiera « du » ; néanmoins, on n'est pas forcé de faire référence à ce désir que l'on a mentionné, d'une manière ou d'une autre, et on peut encore utiliser « de ». Le cas d'une répétition est admis dans ce contexte en cela qu'elle ajoute un effet d'insistence sur la contradiction entre ce qui a été annoncé etce qui est réellement fait, insinuant de la sorte un certain manque d'orthodoxie dans le comportement.

*« Désir » identifié à « volonté »*

- Il m'ont bien parlé de leur curiosité à propos de mon projet et de leur volonté de s'entretenir avec moi dans les instants qui allaient suivre  pour obtenir autant d'information que je pourrais leur en fournir, mais plus les minutes s’écoulent, plus leur absence du/de désir de communiquer avec moi est évidente.

*Répétition*

- Il m'ont bien parlé de leur curiosité à propos de mon projet et de leur désir de communiquer avec moi dans les instants qui allaient suivre  pour obtenir autant d'information que je pourrais leur en fournir, mais plus les minutes s’écoulent, plus leur absence du/de désir de communiquer avec moi est évidente.

Comment: Pour ceux qui ont voté "--" pour cette réponse, je ne pense pas qu'elle soit pire que celle de Lambie.

Comment: @Oreste Comme d'habitude, parti-pris sans discussion !  À la tête du client ! Je vous remercie  de contribuer des remarques constructives.