# Question about articles des/de

Tags: articles

I was reading a French magazine "Le Point" and I came up with certain phrases where I am confused as to the preposition/article *des/de*? Can you help me out please?

I know that if an adjective comes before the noun like *belles choses* - it becomes *de belles choses*.

But the below examples don't fit in that? Here are the examples:

#### Example 1)

> *Pas une semaine ne passe sans que **des actes *d’* espionnage** ou d’infiltration informatique ne soient attribués à la Russie.*

What is the difference between "*des actes **de l'** espionnage*" and the above?

#### Example 2)

La note de Jean Castex dit pourtant ceci :

> *la France **grouille d’espions***

Why is this not "*grouille **des** espions*"

#### Example 3)

> *La mise en œuvre de cette priorité exige aujourd’hui de renforcer l’encadrement **des actions *d’* influence** ou ***d’* ingérence** étrangères qui s’exercent de manière discrète...*"

why is it not "*des actions **de l'** influence or **de l'** ingerence?*" what is the difference?

#### Example 4)

> *le vol **d’** « informations stratégiques. »*

Why is it not "*le vol **des** informations stratégiques*"

#### Example 5)

> *La crainte est alors la même : le vol d’« informations stratégiques. » Qu’il soit le fait d'États ou d’officines privées, le siphonnage de nos secrets est à l’œuvre. Et quiconque assiste au pillage de nos données, dans ce qui **s’apparente à *de la* corruption**, du trafic d’influence...*"

Especially here, why is it "*s'apparente à de la corruption*". Is the "de la" here article partitif? So, does it mean something like "... pillaging of our data seems like (some?) corruption" etc.

#### Example 6)

This one is from "Le Parisien":

> *2021 en télé s’est distinguée par d’incroyables cartons, « HPI » et l’Euro de football en tête, mais aussi **par *des* échecs retentissants** tels « Une affaire française » ou la série « Influences »*.

Here, it is "*par des échecs retentissants*". From what I see in "Le Point", this should also be "***par d’** échecs retentissants*", no?

Comment: You write: "I know that if an adjective comes before the noun like *belles choses*- it becomes "*de belles choses*": not necessarily. It is common but not compulsory in written language and in refined spoken language. *Des* has been used for long in spoken language and is gaining ground in written language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/tout-savoir-sur-ces-combinaisons-de-petits-mots-qui-contiennent-de)

Comment: You start off talking about articles  *de* & *des* : "I know that if an adjective comes before the noun like belles choses- it becomes "de belles choses". But the below examples don't fit in that? Here are the examples:"  The problem is your examples don't fit in with what you have just said. In  *grouille **d**’espions*,  ***d’** informations stratégiques*,  *des actions **d**’influence*,  *s'apparente à **de** la corruption* *d'*/*de* are prepositions, not articles.   In  ***des** échecs retentissants* *des* in an article but the adjective is after the noun.

Comment: Can you please edit (edit link under your post) your question and clarify that point. And please, [be specific](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and ask only one question at a time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leur absence de / du désir de communiquer avec moi est évidente](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49215/leur-absence-de-du-d%c3%a9sir-de-communiquer-avec-moi-est-%c3%a9vidente)

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is classic mixing up of two similar, but distinct grammar words. *De*/*Des* has two distinct use in French, and these do not quite behave the same way

1. It can be a preposition which will contract with a following definite article (de, but *du* and *des* when combining with *le* or *les*)
2. It can be part of the indefinite article (*un*, *une*, *des*)
3. it can be the partitive article (*du*/*de l'*, *de la*/*de l'*, *des*)

**Now, the part that's getting you is that the articles are not allowed after the preposition.** In that situation (not covered by [Stéphane's otherwise excellent answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/tout-savoir-sur-ces-combinaisons-de-petits-mots-qui-contiennent-de?noredirect=1&lq=1)), they vanish, and the naked preposition may then elides as normal for French. Let's run through your cases.

#### Example 1)

In this construction (*acte de*), the de is a proposition, and thus the partitive article what would be *de de l'espionnage* vanishes, leaving *de espionnage*, which promptly elides to *d'espionnage*

#### Example 2)

Same thing: *grouiller de* is a construction with a preposition, so the *des* that would otherwise be there (cf. *Je vois des espions*) vanishes and the prepositions elides before a vowel. *Des* would only be allowed if these were specific spies (i.e. a contract of *de les*), and it's just not possible to construct it that way. You have to be more specific: *La maison grouille des chiens de ma mère*.

#### Example 3)

Same as example 1.

#### Example 4)

Exactly the same as example two, except that *des* can readily be dropped in this one and still be grammatical, but *only* if referring to specific, known information (*de les* → *des*).

#### Example 5)

Yes: *de la* is just the normal singular feminine form of the partitive article. It only looks weird because English wouldn't use articles before non-definite mass nouns.

#### Example 6)

This is a classic contracted *de les* because the failures in questions are specific (and in fact explicitly listed!) thus requiring the definite article.

Comment: In example 2, is *des* in *des espions* an indefinite article?

Comment: In example 4, did you mean to say that *des* can be *kept* and still be grammatical? Ie saying that "le vol des informations strategiques" can be correct?

Comment: @silph In *voir des espions*, yes that is just a normal plural indefinite article. "Le vol des informations strategiques" is grammatical, but as noted, it has a different meaning. It's pretty much the nuance between "theft of strategic data" (*de des* turning into *d'* as explained above under example 2) and "theft of the strategic data". (*de les* turning into *des*, like in the contrastive sentence I gave).