# La place d'Armes / La Place des Arts

Tags: expressions, articles, noms

> La place **d**'Armes est une place du Vieux-Québec située au nord du
> château Frontenac.

([lien](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Place_d%27Armes_(Qu%C3%A9bec)))

> La Place **des** Arts est le plus vaste complexe culturel et artistique au
> Canada.

([lien](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Place_des_Arts))

Pourquoi dit-on *La place d'Armes* et non *La place **des** Armes* alors que l'on dit *La Place **des** Arts* ? Et pourquoi il y a un *p* minuscule dans le premier nom, dans le mot *place* ?

Answer (score 2):

Dans la *place d'armes* le *d'* résulte de la contraction de la préposition *de* avec l'article indéfini pluriel *des* (le sens est donc celui de la **place de des armes*, mais ça ne se dit pas).

Dans la *Place des arts*, le *des* résulte de la contraction de la préposition *des* avec l'article défini pluriels *les* (le sens est donc celui de la **Place de les arts*, mais à nouveau ça ne se dit pas).

De mémoire, il y a quelque part question avec une réponse plus complète sur la préposition *de* et ses contractions et les confusions possibles avec les articles indéfinis et partitifs, mais je ne l'ai pas retrouvée.

Comment: Gendarmes contre gadzarts ;-)

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Oui, je comprends cette contraction, _de = de + des_. Par contre, je ne comprends pas pourquoi il y a un article indéfini devant _armes_ et un article défini devant _arts_. À mon avis, la même logique devrait s'appliquer aux deux noms.

Comment: Place d'armes est une expression très ancienne que l'on peut considérer comme figée, à l'image de *gens d'armes* (gendarmes). Dict. de l'Académie, 1re éd., 1694: *Places d’armes. Terme de guerre qui se dit d’un lieu spatieux, destiné pour y ranger des troupes en bataille. Dans cette ville il y a une tres-belle Place d’armes, capable de contenir six mille hommes rangez en bataille. la place d’armes du Camp estoit vaste & spatieuse. on avoit fait dans la tranchée des places d’armes de distance en distance pour repousser les sorties des ennemis, & soustenir les travailleurs.*

Comment: @jlliagre _que l'on peut considérer comme figée_ Je comprends mieux maintenant, merci.

Comment: Les arts sont définis. Chaque époque a sa classification, mais qu'il y en ait neuf avec chacun leur muse ou six auxquels ont vient ajouter un septième, huitième,... au grés des modes, pour les utilisateurs de l'expression l'ensemble est bien défini. Dans place d'armes, ni la nature ni le nombre de celles-ci sont fixés, même simplement par convention.

Comment: Il y a deux réponse concernées à deux questions différentes. [Celle de Stéphane](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11570/926) décrit les règles principale de ces articles et de leur élision. [La mienne](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49401/926) explique additionnellement que l'article partitif disparaît après la préposition (comme dans le cas présent avec "place d'Armes").

Comment: _Un francophone_, D'accord, merci. Je pensais que l'on pouvait parler d'armes en général, _toutes les armes_. Ça dépend finalement du point de vue.

Comment: @Circeus Merci. Je pensais que l'on pouvait parler de toutes les armes, en général. _La place d'Armes_ = _La place de + les Armes_. Voir les armes en tant que complexe.

Comment: Il est aussi possible que ce soit un usage obsolète qui s'est maintenu à ce jour. c'est une situation commune en toponymie. La première apparition n'est pas certaine (cet espage exite au moins depuis le 17e siècle), mais le nom était en usage sous cette forme au moments de la conquête en 1760.

Comment: Au contraire de gendarme, on perçoit encode l'origine, mais c'est une locution quasiment tout autant figée. Au fait, le terme est toujours utilisé dans l'armée pour désigner le lieu où se passe les cérémonies dans une caserne. Ça ne m'étonnerait pas -- mais je n'ai pas cherché à vérifier -- que dans les villes possédant lieu ainsi nommé, il soit originellement une place d'armes dans ce sens-là.

Answer (score 1):

*Et pourquoi il y a un p minuscule dans le premier nom, dans le mot place ?*

**La place d'Armes** est une « vraie » place, [répertoriée](https://toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/ToposWeb/fiche.aspx?no_seq=182948) par la commission de toponymie du Québec. Les noms de voies (odonymes) sont des mots génériques; ils ne prennent pas de majuscule en français, sauf bien sûr en début de phrase.

**La Place des Arts** (aussi connue sous l'abréviation PDA) n'est pas répertoriée en tant que voie. Elle a d'ailleurs une adresse principale qui fait référence à une « vraie » voie : *175, rue Sainte-Catherine Ouest, Montréal, QC H2X 1Z8 Québec, Canada*. Place des Arts est un nom propre qui désigne un vaste complexe culturel et artistique. En tant que nom propre, il conserve sa majuscule initiale à l'intérieur d'une phrase.

Comment: Il y a aussi une station de métro qui s'appelle _Place d'Armes_ [lien](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Place-d%27Armes_(m%C3%A9tro_de_Montr%C3%A9al))

Comment: @Oreste Elle s'appelle plus précisément **Place-d'Armes**, avec une majuscule et un trait d'union. C'est un nom propre.

Comment: Oui. Mais _La place d'Armes_ et _La Place des Arts_ sont aussi des noms propres, je crois ?

Comment: Voir [aussi](https://toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/ToposWeb/recherche.aspx?s=place+d%27armes), c'est le même genre de logiqueque les [voies de communication](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3355).

Comment: @Oreste *Armes* est un nom propre mais place est un nom commun. *Place des Arts* est un nom propre mais le fait qu'il soit précédé d'un article justifie l'absence de trait d'union. Pour la station de métro, on met un trait d'union car il s'agit d'un seul nom composé, jamais d'article devant lui. Le trait d'union distingue la station de métro du lieu dont elle tire son nom.

Comment: @LétaleD'incivilisation Merci :)

Comment: jlliagre Merci. :) Il y a trop de règles...

Comment: @Oreste avec parfois quelques variations dans le temps ou suivant les pays... https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_des_majuscules_en_fran%C3%A7ais