# How to say "of" vs "of the"?

Tags: de

Is it correct to say that I can use "de" to say "of", in both masculine/feminine and plural?
And to use "du, de la, des" to say "of the"?

Examples in plural:

```
Le prix de voitures... (the price of cars)
Le prix des voitures... (the price of the cars)

Le jeu d'enfants...
Le jeu des enfants...
```

Comment: Not exactly. "Le prix de voitures" calls for a specification of which types of cars. It doesn't directly translate to "the price of cars" which can stay indefinite and would be better translated by "le prix des voitures". "Le prix de voitures _à quatre portes_" - maybe. It doesn't ring quite natural. Same for "le jeu d'enfants". "_un_ jeu d'enfant" works better. There is something going on with definite/indefinite here.

Comment: Deciding whether to translate "of the" or "of" as "des" or "de" is quite complicated, because English and French grammar don't correspond in this respect. The answer to [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49399/question-about-articles-des-de) sheds some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

*Le prix **de** voitures* doesn't sound right.

We would use *le prix **des** voitures* in both cases. The first one means *Le prix des voitures **en général*** and the second one *Le prix des voitures **en particulier, de celle dont on parle.***

***Jeu d'enfant*** is used in the idiom: ***C'est un jeu d'enfant***. The meaning is similar to *It's a piece of cake* and almost identical to *It's child's play*.

***Le jeu d'enfant*** is possible but might somewhat clash with the idiom. Depending on the context, I might use something different like *le jeu pour enfants* maybe.

***Le jeu des enfants*** is fine, meaning "their game."

Comment: A more literal translation of *c'est un jeu d'enfant* would be the idiom [*it's child's play*.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/child%27s%20play)